# Automation tests passed in local but failed in Jenkins get Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000

Tags: jenkins, testing, automation, cypress

In my project I am using React for frontend, Python/Django for backend and Cypress for end to end testing. Locally all the test cases passess. But when I push my code to github one of this test Fails  `name: Run tests`.

Below is the tests.yml file

tests.yml

```
name: Tests
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'
      - '*/*'
      - '!master'
      - '!main'
jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Fetch apiUrl
        run: echo ::set-output name=apiUrl::$(jq -r .env.apiUrl cypress.json)/ping
        id: fetchApiUrl
      - name: Ensure mochawesome
        run: 'jq -r ".[\"devDependencies\"] |= (.mochawesome = \"^6.2.2\")" package.json > package.json.tmp && mv package.json.tmp package.json'
      - name: Install deps
        run: npm install
      - name: Update test reporter
        run: 'jq -M ". + {\"reporter\": \"mochawesome\", \"reporterOptions\": { \"reportDir\": \"cypress/results\", \"overwrite\": false, \"html\": false, \"json\": true }}" cypress.json > cypress.json.tmp && mv cypress.json.tmp cypress.json'
      - name: Run tests
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          build: npm run build
          start: npm run start
          wait-on: ${{ steps.fetchApiUrl.outputs.apiUrl }}
```

Below is cypress.json

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:3000",
  "env": {
    "apiUrl": "http://localhost:3000/api"
  }
}
```

I am getting below error

```
> echo build your fullstack app here

build your fullstack app here
start server "npm run start command "npm run start"
current working directory "/home/runner/work/transaction-management-fullstack-level-1_83d83d9-h61jhd-cihba8/transaction-management-fullstack-level-1_83d83d9-h61jhd-cihba8"
waiting on "http://localhost:3000/api/ping" with timeout of 60 seconds
/usr/local/bin/npm run start

> account-management-fullstack-level-1@0.0.1 start
> echo start your fullstack app here

start your fullstack app here
http://localhost:3000/api/ping timed out on retry 91 of 3, elapsed 90258ms, limit 90000ms
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
```

Comment: As the error says, your locally hosted app is not up even after 90 seconds. Check if you have you started appropriately?

Comment: When I run `http://localhost:3000/api/ping` locally it works. After pushing to github above `tests.yml` fails, not sure why

Answer (score 0):

Where are you running your tests in Jenkins ? Is it within the docker with help of docker-compose ?? Then you should change your URL to be something like below. If your docker-compose looks like this, then your URL should be

```
version: "3"
services:
  test-repo:
    image: test-repo
    container_name: test-repo
    network_mode: host
```

`http://test-repo:3000`